# How to archive a git repository which uses LFS?

Tags: git, github, git-lfs, git-bundle

I'm looking to archive a git repository to a regular file server for a client.

Previously I've used `git bundle create [path] --all`
to do this and it's worked well.

However this repository is using Git LFS, and the LFS files aren't included in the bundle created using the above command.

1. How can I easily export all commits, branches and history for the
   repository, including LFS files?
2. Is this possible with LFS?

Comment: I need this capability as well. Have you tried using `git lfs fetch --all` or similar before creating the bundle? If that doesn't work, let me know and I'll add a bounty to this question.

Answer (score 1):

The only way i figured out, is to zip and copy the tracked files and store them next to the repository. Every git-lfs system got a location where the versions of the tracked files are stored.

I will try to figure out something better, since im trying this aswel. If u find a solution, let me know pls